# edit message when someone reacts to it not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I have been trying to make a discord bot that would edit the message whenever you add a reaction to that message but for some reason whenever I react the message doesn't edit, and I don't get any errors. Anyone know why this happens? Everything works up to the reaction part

Keep in mind I'm fairly new to python so I probably missed something basic here.

Yes I have the token in the code just didn't send it here for obvious reasons

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.utils import get
import asyncio
import requests
import pprint

client = Bot('!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("BOT READY FFS")




partymembers = []


@client.event
async def on_message(message):

  def check(reaction, user):
    return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ['✅']

  if message.content.startswith('d!createparty'):
    message1 = message.content.split()
    floor = message1[1]
    reqslvl = message1[2]
    dupes = message1[3]
    if floor not in ['entrance', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4']:
        return
    elif dupes not in ['yes', 'no']:
        return
    else:
      channel = client.get_channel(738323108158767134)
      partycreator = message.author.id
      partymembers.append("<@" + str(partycreator) + ">")
      embed1=discord.Embed(color=0x15ff00)
      embed1.add_field(name="Party Members:", value=partymembers, inline=False)
      embed1.add_field(name="Floor:", value=floor, inline=False)
      embed1.add_field(name="Level req:", value=reqslvl, inline=False)
      embed1.add_field(name="Dupes:", value=dupes, inline=False)
      coolembedmsg = await channel.send(embed=embed1)
      await coolembedmsg.add_reaction('✅')
      messageid = message.id
      memberjoin = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)
      if memberjoin:
        users = set()
        for reaction in message.reactions:
          async for user in reaction.users():
            users.append(user)
            if len(users) > 5:
              return
            else:
              # this is where message would be edited, probably something to do with the list not being updated or something
              for newmember in users:
                partymembers.append(newmember)
                embed2=discord.Embed(color=0x15ff00)
                embed2.add_field(name="Party Members:", value=partymembers, inline=False)
                embed2.add_field(name="Floor:", value=floor, inline=False)
                embed2.add_field(name="Level req:", value=reqslvl, inline=False)
                embed2.add_field(name="Dupes:", value=dupes, inline=False)
                await coolembedmsg.edit(embed=embed2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a timeout to your wait_for() event

```py
memberjoin = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60.0, check=check)
```

Comment: tru and change memberjoin to reaction, user.    like this ->> 

**reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60.0, check=check)**

Comment: im pretty sure that wont be changing anything since the memberjoin is just a thing for confirmation, might be wrong here dunno

Comment: @SkeldrBoii actually it might be the fix. the on_reaction_add event returns reaction and user.

after you change memberjoin to 'reaction, user' change your if statement to   --> **if reaction.emoji == '✅':**

also change your check function to  --> **return reaction.message.id == msg.id and user == ctx.author**

Comment: do i leave the ctx.author like that or do i replace ctx with something?